# What's the right way of saying this?

Tags: phrases

I want to know the right way of saying the following phrase:

> 1, "Account holder name."
>
> 2, "Account's holder name."

I would like to know which of previous phrases is correct and if there is a different way to say this phrase please let me know.

I want to use this phrase to ask my customers for the name of the owner of the account like in a phrase like "May I have the account's holder name please." Please help me out because I really want to know.

Comment: You are asking for the name of the account holder (the person who holds the account). Thus it's *account holder's name.* One doesn't really approach this from the account, so you don't ask about the *account's holder.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possession belongs to the holder of the account, not the account itself. Therefore you want to ask your customers for the "account holder's name."

Comment: You do not address the option *account holder name*.